# Proper way of dealing with errors when fitting many models by group with dplyr::do

Tags: r, dplyr, lm

Using `dplyr::do`, it can be pretty simple to fit multiple models by group as shown below:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(100)
tbl <- tibble(
  group_id = rep(1:3, each = 10),
  y1 = rnorm(30),
  y2 = runif(30),
  x1 = rnorm(30),
  x2 = runif(30)
)

tbl %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  do(
    model1 = lm(y1 ~ x1 + x2, data = .),
    model2 = lm(y2 ~ x1 + x2, data = .)
  )
#> Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   group_id model1   model2  
#> *    <int> <list>   <list>  
#> 1        1 <S3: lm> <S3: lm>
#> 2        2 <S3: lm> <S3: lm>
#> 3        3 <S3: lm> <S3: lm>
```

This is the ideal format to use for `broom::tidy` and `broom::glance` to extract the `r.squared` and coefficients by group. However, there is a problem when one group, here with `group_id == 3`, has all missing values:

```r
tbl2 <- mutate(tbl, y2 = c(runif(20), rep(NA, 10)))

tbl2 %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  do(
    model1 = lm(y1 ~ x1 + x2, data = .),
    model2 = lm(y2 ~ x1 + x2, data = .)
  )
#> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...): 0 (non-NA) cases
```

As expected, because there are no non-missing values of `y2` for `group_id == 3`, `model2` fails to fit anything. Other questions I have found suggest simply deleting the rows with `NA` values before fitting, however I do not want to do this because then I would lose successful fits of `model1`. Another approach I thought of was to catch the error with `try`, but I have not been able to replace only the errors with missing values. I tried many variations on the below code that uses `purrr::modify_if`, but do not know why the value is not replaced (for example,

```r
modify_if(list(1, "a", TRUE), ~ inherits(., "numeric"), `is.na<-`)
```

works fine.) You can see that using `map` and `inherits` correctly spots which of the cells is class `try-error`, but wrapping it inside `modify_if` makes it no longer spotted.

```r
tbl2 %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  do(
    model1 = lm(y1 ~ x1 + x2, data = .),
    model2 = try(
      lm(y2 ~ x1 + x2, data = .),
      silent = TRUE
    )
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate_all(
    function(col) map_lgl(col, function(cell) inherits(cell, "try-error"))
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   group_id model1 model2
#>   <lgl>    <lgl>  <lgl> 
#> 1 FALSE    FALSE  FALSE 
#> 2 FALSE    FALSE  FALSE 
#> 3 FALSE    FALSE  TRUE

tbl2 %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  do(
    model1 = lm(y1 ~ x1 + x2, data = .),
    model2 = try(
      lm(y2 ~ x1 + x2, data = .),
      silent = TRUE
    )
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate_at(
    .vars = vars(starts_with("model_")),
    .funs = function(col) {
      modify_if(
        .x = col,
        .p = function(cell) inherits(cell, "try-error"),
        .f = function(cell) unclass(`is.na<-`(cell)))
    }
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   group_id model1   model2         
#> *    <int> <list>   <list>         
#> 1        1 <S3: lm> <S3: lm>       
#> 2        2 <S3: lm> <S3: lm>       
#> 3        3 <S3: lm> <S3: try-error>
```

Created on 2018-04-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

My actual data have ~ 80k groups and ~ 10 models for reference. Any suggestions for improving this code or a better way to catch the errors would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the best way I found of dealing with this problem. Instead of using `modify` to try and replace the error models, it's better to filter them out and replace the missing rows after `glance`. This is because `glance` doesn't work well with malformed `lm` output anyway.

```
tbl2 %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  do(
    model1 = lm(y1 ~ x1 + x2, data = .),
    model2 = try(
      lm(y2 ~ x1 + x2, data = .),
      silent = TRUE
    )
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  gather(model, lm, starts_with("model")) %>%
  mutate(error = map_lgl(lm, ~inherits(., "try-error"))) %>%
  filter(error == FALSE) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  glance(lm) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(group_id = 1:3, model = c("model1", "model2"))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 14
#>   group_id model  error r.squared adj.r.squared  sigma statistic p.value
#>      <int> <chr>  <lgl>     <dbl>         <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1        1 model1 FALSE    0.0215       -0.258   0.629    0.0769   0.927
#> 2        1 model2 FALSE    0.107        -0.149   0.329    0.418    0.674
#> 3        2 model1 FALSE    0.208        -0.0184  0.868    0.919    0.442
#> 4        2 model2 FALSE    0.0808       -0.182   0.362    0.308    0.745
#> 5        3 model1 FALSE    0.0707       -0.195   0.738    0.266    0.774
#> 6        3 model2 NA      NA            NA      NA       NA       NA    
#> # ... with 6 more variables: df <int>, logLik <dbl>, AIC <dbl>, BIC <dbl>,
#> #   deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>
```